# Loading data to MySQL table from Hive using Sqoop/Oozie

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop, oozie

I am facing some grave issue (tried unsuccessful 196 times) while loading data using Sqoop (sqoop command inside Oozie) to MySQL table. If there is only one column of data in HDFS (here foo) then there is no issue but when there are more than 1 column e.g. 2 columns, data does not get loaded to MySQL.

If I run the Sqoop by itself, then the data gets loaded to MySQL but when I put inside Oozie, data does not get laoded.

The workflow.xml has 2 parts, 1st it loads data from Hive table to HDFS and 2nd loads data from HDFS to MySQL.

I am using ClouderaVM.

Error message is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1    a"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
```

-

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (
id int,
city string
 )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/cloudera/foo';
```

-

```
$ vi foo
1   a
4   b

hive> load data local inpath '/home/cloudera/foo' into table foo;
```

-

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `foo` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `city` varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL );
```

-

workflow.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="etl-wf">
    <start to="hive-node"/>

    <action name="hive-node">
    <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
             <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
             <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <job-xml>hive-site.xml</job-xml>
       <script>script.q</script>
    </hive>
    <ok to="sqoop-node"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
 </action>

 <action name="sqoop-node">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <command>export --connect jdbc:mysql://www.abc.net/test --username rio --password r005 --table foo  --export-dir /user/cloudera/test --input-fields-terminated-by '\t' --input-lines-terminated-by '\n'</command>
    </sqoop>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>


<kill name="fail">
    <message>Hive failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>

</workflow-app>
```

Note: here 1st part works i.e. data gets laoded to test table in hive but does not get loaded from hdfs: /user/cloudera/test to MySQL table foo.

-

vi script.q:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
id int,
city string
  )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION
 '/user/cloudera/test';

INSERT OVERWRITE table test SELECT * FROM foo;
```

-

stderr logs

```
Note: /tmp/sqoop-mapred/compile/d4f769ef09667984820f21a38ae27bb4/foo.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1    a"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
at java
java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1    a"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
at java
java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at  org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1    a"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
at java
Intercepting System.exit(1)
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]
```

-

Answer (score 1):

This could be a transformer in the logger but still is worth looking into: you have 4 spaces in "1    a". Did you check what's in your file in hdfs? Are columns delimited by \t ?

Comment: I did: hadoop fs -get test/000000_0. I saw the file from vim and they are tab separated.

Comment: Task Logs says: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 a"

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1    a"

is the probelm here. Change your mysql script and use `mysql> CREATE TABLE`foo`(`id`varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,`city`varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL );`

The problem is that the first column from your data is being inferred as an integer. This is not the solution to your problem. I have just recommended this approach as a test to check whether number format is the issue at your end or not. Please perform this and let us know. We will try to help you further.

P.S: It is very much possible that the character between 1 and a is not a tab separator. Probably spaces maybe.

Comment: I did modify the MySQL table schema but this time log message was: Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:834)
    at foo.__loadFromFields(foo.java:198)
    at foo.parse(foo.java:147)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMa

Comment: @Rio Did you verify that the separator between 1 and a is a tab character (\t) ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to escape your parameters when using Oozie. All escape sequences and the surrounding single and double quotes must be removed.
Your sqoop command in oozie workflow should be like below :

export --connect jdbc:mysql://www.abc.net/test --username rio --password r005 --table foo  --export-dir /user/cloudera/test --input-fields-terminated-by \t --input-lines-terminated-by \n

There should not be any single quotes surrounding \t and \n.

Answer (score 0):

probable cause may be that data is not inserted well in hive table
Can you print the result of following command?

```
hive -e "select id from foo;"
```

if the above query prints as

```
1   a
4   b
```

Then edit your input file to have tab or change your delimiter.